# A file is no longer in HEAD revision but can't locate commit where file was deleted

Tags: git

I've scoured my history and have found nothing. I can see commits where it was created and modified, but it no longer exists and I can't figure out where it was deleted.

for example:

`git log --full-history --all --diff-filter=D --summary -- path/to/file`

returns nothing. Also, just to make sure my working copy wasn't somehow out of sync with git's state (is this even possible?) i tried:

`git checkout -- path/to/file`

I have also tried * lots * of log commands. I checked on github (where repo is hosted) and file is not that either. I checked to make sure that the last commit I could find the file in was fully merged and it was (`git branch --merged` contains branch with file)

I know that merge commits don't seem to show a log of what changed, is it possible that I accidentally deleted the files during a merge somehow ? Or would that still show up in the log? Is there a way to get some log information on a merge commit?

**update:**

here is the (abridged) output of this command:

`git log --oneline -p -M --follow HEAD -- path/to/file`

```
aaaaa this commit creates it again ?
diff --git a/path/to/file b/path/to/file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..3333333
--- /dev/null
+++ b/path/to/file

bbbbb this commit modifies it
diff --git a/path/to/file b/path/to/file
index 1111111..2222222 100644
--- a/path/to/file
+++ b/path/to/file

ccccc this commit creates the file
diff --git a/path/to/file b/path/to/file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..11111111
--- /dev/null
+++ b/path/to/file
```

Comment: Keep it simple. What happens when you do e.g. `git log --oneline -- path/to/file`?

Comment: @jthill it shows one commit (the commit where I added the file back into the tree)

Comment: @jthill if I checkout the commit immediately prior to that commit the `--oneline` command outputs nothing. If I do `git log --oneline --follow HEAD -- path/to/file` it shows 1 commit which created the file, and a 2nd commit where it was modified. Still no deletion commit. There also isn't any evidence in the log of the file getting renamed either.

Comment: Please try to do less characterization and omitting and hand-editing of results, less piling on of options without explanation or apparent reason, and more presentation of what you're actually seeing.  Going on what I can see here, and having to guess which of your edits and omissions and characterizations have least obfuscated the situation, I'd guess the file actually does exist in HEAD, and you've deleted it from the index by some means, likely `git rm`.  My favorite quick test whether a file actually exists in a commit is `git rev-parse commit:path/to/file`.

Comment: As yet another approach, you could harness git bisect with the <cmd> option to find out where a file got added/removed/changed.

Comment: @jthill thanks for your help, I didn't know about the `-c` flag which allowed me to find the merge commit in question, though I still feel like something strange is happening since I can't get git log to explicitly state that the file was deleted ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file has been deleted or renamed, in the output of `git log --all --oneline -c -p -- path_to_file` it's expected to find `--- a/path/to/file +++ /dev/null`. That's the commit that deleted or renamed the file. If the deletion or rename happened in a merge commit, `-c` can output the diff stat too.

Comment: NEVERMIND. I didn't try `-c` switch. thank you !! It was an "octopus" merge that I botched I guess.

Comment: `-c` uncovered the relevant merge commit, and `git show --stat` shows the file being removed (or truncated, same output) but there is still no way for me to get it to output the `--- a/path/to/file +++ /dev/null` line. not with `-p` or `--raw`. oh well :p